Replicating Econometrics Research
I took a course on Econometrics last year which covered OLS, GLS, panel data, binary dependent variables, instrumental variables, experiments and quasi-experiments, big data, time-series forecasting, dynamic causal effects and cointegration.
From the best of my knowledge, it was broadly based on chapters from Jeffrey M. Wooldridge's Introductory Econometrics.
Though the teaching involved many references to case studies alongside the theory, I did not take away as many practical skills as I would have hoped.
I was looking around for replicable econometrics studies so that I could have a go at practising some of the relevant data-cleansing, joining and regressions involved. I came across a website with Rtutor exercises but there seems to be some compatibility issues with more recent versions of R.
Could anyone recommend places where I can find replicable studies with data sources so that I can practice some of the data-analyses with some sort of verification?
Thanks in advance!

If you pick recent highly published papers, check out the supplementary material section which will have either directly the package or provide a link.
Otherwise check out also these:

https://i4replication.org/database.html
https://replication.uni-goettingen.de/
https://dataverse.harvard.edu/


Also, check out any free "R for econometrics" books on the internet. There should be plenty of R examples in those.

Christoph Hanck (who participates at Cross Validated here) has coauthored a textbook "Introduction to Econometrics with R" following Stock & Watson "Introduction to Econometrics".

ICPSR has dataset for many recently published papers.
https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/pages/

Bruce Hansen's graduate Econometrics textbook features a few replication examples that are good for review; I especially recall the FWL exercises as helpful.
